# Javascript Counting Date From Custom Datetime

Tags: date, datetime, format, counting

first i have this date format when my script insert to database mysql

```
Jul-6-2018 08:43:17 PM
```

I want to have a javascript count date time from that date format, how to make this possible?

for example of counting format,

```
24 hours 13 minutes 20 seconds
```

the counting should be start when the database is insert, please someone help me to figure out this,

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery, then this plugin: https://timeago.yarp.com/ provides text "translations" of time periods.